# Follow up call to my API returns Preflight HTTP status error

Tags: php, mysql, angular, api, xampp

I have been struggling with a strange issue for about a week now. I have searched through the answers here and elsewhere on the internet and I'm not quite sure what my specific issue might be. I do however think the error message I am getting doesn't have anything to do with my actual error. I thank you for any help or suggestions you might have.

My setup is as follows (all running locally):

1. Frontend website - Angular - running on standard ng serve
2. Backend API - PHP / MySQL - hosted locally via XAMPP

The error:

```
{"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://192.168.64.2/resourcer/api/menu/47693eb3-ca82-467b-af68-020150a5e4a6","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://192.168.64.2/resourcer/api/menu/47693eb3-ca82-467b-af68-020150a5e4a6: 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

The concept:

1. Log in, authenticate on the php side, get jwt token.
2. The jwt token has a property called 'access'. I use this to return the menu based on the role.
3. Once I receive the jwt, I set the user object, append the jwt to bearer token auth header.
4. Call the retrieve menu call with the access property received from the server.

All of this works up until I change user. I have added 2 users to test the different menu items coming back, and when I log a user out (clear local storage), I try the second user's credentials.

I log in successfully, get the jwt and the user object, but when I request the menu I get the error message. I cannot get past this at all. The only way this gets fixed is by commenting all the code required to return the menu and just echo 'ok'. Then I do a request, get the ok, uncomment the code and then it's all back to normal until I log out again.

Have no idea what on earth is going on. Here is my code:

Angular Interceptor Service:

```
export class InterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}

  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler,
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    const currentUser = this.authService.currentUserValue;

    if (currentUser && currentUser.token) {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          Accept: 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${currentUser.token}`,
        },
      });
    } else {
      request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
          Accept: 'application/json',
        },
      });
    }

    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Angular Auth Service:

```
signIn(signinCredentials: AuthCredentials) {
    return this.dataService.signIn(signinCredentials).pipe(
      map((data) => {
        const helper = new JwtHelperService();
        const decoded = helper.decodeToken(data.jwt);
        const user: User = decoded.data;
        user.token = data.jwt;

        localStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
        this.currentUserSubject.next(user);
        return user;
      }),
    );
  }

logout() {
    localStorage.removeItem('currentUser');
    localStorage.removeItem('navItems');
    this.currentUserSubject.next(null);
  }
```

Angular Login Page:

```
signIn() {
    this.submitted = true;
    this.loading = true;

    this.authService
      .signIn(this.signinCredentials)
      .pipe(first())
      .subscribe(
        (data) => {
          this.currentUser = this.authService.currentUserValue;
          this.getMenu();
        },
        (error) => {
          this.error = error;
          this.loading = false;
        },
      );
  }

getMenu() {
    this.dataService.getNavigationItems(this.currentUser.access).subscribe(
      (menu) => {
        if (menu) {
          this.envService.setNavItems(menu.menu);
          this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        } else {
          this.authService.logout();
          location.reload(true);
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        this.authService.logout();
        location.reload(true);
      },
    );
  }
```

Now on my PHP side, I use an .htaccess file to redirect my URL:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule app/api/ app/api/index.php
```

PHP Index:

```
<?php

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS");
header("Access-Control-Max-Age: 3600");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

define('PROJECT_ROOT_PATH', __DIR__);

include_once 'config/db.php';

--- Controller imports etc happen here

$uri = parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], PHP_URL_PATH);
$uri = explode('/', $uri);
$requestMethod = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];

$headerToken = getBearerToken();

if (isset($uri[3])) {
    switch ($uri[3]) {
        case 'users':
            $userId = null;
            if (isset($uri[4])) {
                $userId = (int) $uri[4];
            }
            $controller = new UserController($db, $requestMethod, $userId, $headerToken);
            $controller->processRequest();
            break;
        case 'companies':
            $companyReference = null;
            if (isset($uri[4])) {
                $companyReference = $uri[4];
            }
            $controller = new CompanyController($db, $requestMethod, $companyReference, $headerToken);
            $controller->processRequest();
            break;
        case 'login':
            $controller = new LoginController($db);
            $controller->login();
            break;
        case 'menu':
            $roleGuid = null;
            if (isset($uri[4])) {
                $roleGuid = $uri[4];
            }
            $controller = new MenuController($db, $roleGuid, $headerToken);
            $controller->getMenuItems();
            break;
        default:
            header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
            exit();
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
    exit();
}

function getAuthorizationHeader()
{
    $headers = null;
    if (isset($_SERVER['Authorization'])) {
        $headers = trim($_SERVER["Authorization"]);
    } else if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'])) {
        $headers = trim($_SERVER["HTTP_AUTHORIZATION"]);
    } elseif (function_exists('apache_request_headers')) {
        $requestHeaders = apache_request_headers();
        $requestHeaders = array_combine(array_map('ucwords', array_keys($requestHeaders)), array_values($requestHeaders));
        if (isset($requestHeaders['Authorization'])) {
            $headers = trim($requestHeaders['Authorization']);
        }
    }
    return $headers;
}

function getBearerToken()
{
    $headers = getAuthorizationHeader();
    if (!empty($headers)) {
        if (preg_match('/Bearer\s(\S+)/', $headers, $matches)) {
            return $matches[1];
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

When I mentioned that I comment out the controller code with an echo ok, and it works, happens in this index file.

I'm stumped.

Comment: Sounds like your PHP script dies with a fatal error or something - have you checked the error logs? // When you get that message in regard to the pre-flight request - then presumably it tries to do something at that point, with data that is not actually set properly. I see you checking the request method - but then you don’t seem to actually respond differently, based on that? […]

Comment: […] For the pre-flight request with OPTIONS method, you should not attempt to do all that stuff you are doing there, but _just_ give a 200 OK response, plus the relevant CORS headers. All actual data processing, should only happen when you handle the _actual_ request.

Comment: So I tried going over the tutorial I used for the API, and it seems I missed some bits with regards to the responses and headers. I also thought that the code was dying, thanks, will check out the errors. Looks like it's working for now, let me see if it breaks again.